# What is the difference between "datetime.timedelta" and "dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta" when working only with days?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

What is the difference between [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) (from Python's standard library) and [`dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) when working only with days?

As far as I understand, `timedelta` only supports days (and weeks), while `relativedelta` adds support for periods defined in terms of years, months, weeks or days, as well as defining absolute values for year, month or day. *(remember, for the purposes of this question, I don't have to worry about hours, minutes or seconds)*

Considering that I'm only working with [`datetime.date`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) objects, and only interested in periods defined by the number of days, what's the difference between `timedelta` and `relativedelta`? Is there any difference?

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

i = -1  # This could have been any integer, positive or negative
someday = date.today()
# Is there any difference between these two lines?
otherday = someday + timedelta(days=i)
otherday = someday + relativedelta(days=i)
```

Comment: If you are only interested in deltas in days between dates, just use the standard library's `dateime.timedelta` which will achieve what you want and avoid the dependency on the external `dateutil` package.

Comment: It is worth saying that on top of saving one extra dependency, computing deltas in days between dates is multiple times faster with timedelta than relativedelta. (~10 times)

Comment: None of the answers actually explains the difference, the answer here does it perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728775/how-to-convert-dateutil-relativedelta-object-to-datetime-timedelta-object

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`dateutil` is an extension package to the python standard `datetime` module. As you say, it provides extra functionality, such as timedeltas that are expressed in units larger than a day.

This is useful if you have to ask questions such as how many months can I save before my girlfriend's birthday comes up, or what's the last Friday in the month? This hides complex calculations that are caused by the different lengths of the months, or extra days in leap years.

In your case, you are only interested in the number of days. So you'd best use `timedelta` as this avoids an extra dependency on the `dateutil` package.

Answer (score 62):

A `relativedelta` has many more parameters than a `timedelta`:

> ```
> Definition:   relativedelta.relativedelta(self, dt1=None, dt2=None,
> years=0, months=0, days=0, leapdays=0, weeks=0, hours=0, minutes=0,
> seconds=0, microseconds=0, year=None, month=None, day=None,
> weekday=None, yearday=None, nlyearday=None, hour=None, minute=None,
> second=None, microsecond=None)
> ```

with which you can do things like calculate the last Friday in a month:

```
In [14]: import datetime as dt

In [15]: import dateutil.relativedelta as relativedelta

In [16]: today = dt.date.today()

In [17]: rd = relativedelta.relativedelta(day = 31, weekday = relativedelta.FR(-1))

In [18]: today+rd
Out[18]: datetime.date(2012, 9, 28)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer which gave new insight of using a relativedelta for things like "last friday of the month" :) Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

One major difference not highlighted in other answers is the presence of singular and plural nouns for each time difference primitive. While `timedelta` only offers plural nouns (e.g. `hours`, `days`) to denote relative time difference, `relativedelta` offers singular nouns as well (e.g. `hour`, `day`) to denote absolute time information.

This is clear from the definition of the 2 classes:

> ```
> Definition:   datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, 
> milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
>
> Definition:   relativedelta.relativedelta(self, dt1=None, dt2=None,
> years=0, months=0, days=0, leapdays=0, weeks=0, hours=0, minutes=0,
> seconds=0, microseconds=0, year=None, month=None, day=None,
> weekday=None, yearday=None, nlyearday=None, hour=None, minute=None,
> second=None, microsecond=None)
> ```

Now, exactly what does the singular form do? Singular form creates a delta which when added to a `datetime` object, sets that specific date/time primitive in the `datetime` object to that mentioned in the `relativedelta`. Here is a small example:

```python
>>> import datetime as dt; from dateutil.relativedelta import *
>>> NOW = dt.datetime(2018, 11, 17, 9, 6, 31)
>>> NOW
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 17, 9, 6, 31)
>>> NOW + relativedelta(hours=1) #Simply add one hour
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 17, 10, 6, 31)
>>> NOW + relativedelta(hour=1) #Set the hour to 01:00 am
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 17, 1, 6, 31)
```

This can lead to `relativedelta` being used for some interesting applications, which can be complicated to implement using `timedelta`. One that quickly comes to mind is rounding-off.

### An Interesting Application : Quickly Rounding off

I will now show you how `relativedelta` is more expressive when doing rounding off a `datetime` object to the nearest minute, hour, day etc.

#### Rounding off to the nearest hour:

Notice how straightforward it is to round-off using `relativedelta`:

```python
#Using `relativedelta`
NOW + relativedelta(hours=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

#Using `timedelta`
dt.combine(NOW.date(),dt.time(NOW.hour,0,0)) + dt.timedelta(0,60*60,0)
```

Other more complicated rounding-offs are easily achievable using `relativedelta`. However, note that all the round-offs that can be done by `relativedelta` can also be done using `datetime` functions and `timedelta`, only in a slightly more convoluted way.

Comment: The "hours" vs "hour" difference was causing me some head scratching, so thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

As @julien mentioned, `timedelta` is an order of magnitude faster than `relativedelta`. Here is a simple demonstration using days:

```
In [1]: from datetime import date, timedelta
   ...: from dateutil.relativedelta import *
   ...: import timeit

In [2]: def td():
   ...:     return date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
   ...:

In [3]: def rd():
   ...:     return date.today() + relativedelta(days=7)
   ...:

In [4]: timeit.timeit('td()', 'from __main__ import td', number=1000)
Out[4]: 0.0019557802006602287

In [5]: timeit.timeit('rd()', 'from __main__ import rd', number=1000)
Out[5]: 0.014670956879854202
```

If performance is important `relativedelta` should be avoided, unless the task cannot be accomplished using `timedelta` (such as adding a week/month/year delta).

Answer (score -1):

According to https://seihotech.com/comparing-datetime-timedelta-and-dateutil-relativedelta-relativedelta-in-python/

```
datetime.timedelta
```

- a function from the Python standard library
- only works with days

```
dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta
```

- a third-party module
- can work with other date components: eg: hours, minutes, and seconds

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is clearly wrong. [The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) clearly shows that `timedelta` is composed of `days` and `seconds` (and `microseconds`), and additionally accepts `milliseconds`, `minutes`, `hours` and `weeks` (those are converted to the aforementioned three units).