# Elegant way to convert python datetime.timedelta to dateutil.relativedelta

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

Is there an elegant was to convert between `relativedelta` and `timedelta`?

The use case is getting user input ISO date. Python's `isodate` will return either `isodate.duration.Duration` or `datetime.timedelta`.

We need the features of `relativedelta` (per [What is the difference between "datetime.timedelta" and "dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta" when working only with days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433233/what-is-the-difference-between-datetime-timedelta-and-dateutil-relativedelta) -- it does more) so need to convert both these types to a `relativedata`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just take the total number of `seconds` and `microseconds`, that's all a `timedelta` object stores:

```
def to_relativedelta(tdelta):
    return relativedelta(seconds=int(tdelta.total_seconds()),
                         microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)

>>> to_relativedelta(timedelta(seconds=0.3))
relativedelta(microseconds=+300000)
>>> to_relativedelta(timedelta(seconds=3))
relativedelta(seconds=+3)
>>> to_relativedelta(timedelta(seconds=300))
relativedelta(minutes=+5)
>>> to_relativedelta(timedelta(seconds=3000000))
relativedelta(days=+34, hours=+17, minutes=+20)
```

Comment: The microseconds are included in the total_seconds.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Yes, but relativedelta doesn't accept fractional seconds (`relativedelta(seconds=0.3)` gives `relativedelta(seconds=+0)`). Also, as the documentation states, microseconds may not be accurate for very large intervals.

Comment: relativedelta(seconds=0.3) gives relativedelta(seconds=0.3) to me. I'm using python-dateutil 1.5

Comment: @falsetru, that's weird. It should at least normalize to `relativedelta(microseconds=+300000)`. (I'm using version 1.5 on Python 2.7 and 2.0 on Python 3, on Linux.)

Comment: @petr-viktorin, My comment was wrong. I spelled "second" instead of "seconds".

Comment: I've reported a bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/1188507. Still, if you want microseconds in a relativedelta you need to give it explicitly.

Comment: Weird, I thought "at least he should have an int() around total seconds". And now, there it is, but no edit have happened. Perhaps I was blind. :-)

Comment: if you're getting weird numbers on the relativedelta, try using the `.normalized()` method mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = datetime.timedelta(...)
dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(seconds=d.total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're dealing with a timedelta because two datetimes were subtracted.
Relativedelta has dt1 and dt2 arguments in its **init**.

Just pass the two datetimes you used to get your timedelta e and you'll have your relative delta.

Answer (score -1):

Using seconds directly with relativedelta does not populate the months and years fields and there is a reason of course that we wouldn't know if it's a leap year or a month with 31 days.

So something like this:

```
[In]:  tdelta = datetime.now() - datetime(1971, 1, 1)
[In]:  relativedelta(seconds=tdelta.total_seconds())
[Out]: relativedelta(days=+16958, hours=+13, minutes=+19, seconds=+49)
```

gives relative delta with lots of days and no months. While this can be okay in certain cases, in some we might need the years and months. Therefore:

```
def timedelta_to_relativedelta(tdelta):
    assert isinstance(tdelta, timedelta)

    seconds_in = {
        'year'  : 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        'month' : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        'day'   : 24 * 60 * 60,
        'hour'  : 60 * 60,
        'minute': 60
    }

    years, rem = divmod(tdelta.total_seconds(), seconds_in['year'])
    months, rem = divmod(rem, seconds_in['month'])
    days, rem = divmod(rem, seconds_in['day'])
    hours, rem = divmod(rem, seconds_in['hour'])
    minutes, rem = divmod(rem, seconds_in['minute'])
    seconds = rem

    return relativedelta(years=years, months=months, days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

This might not be a very Pythonic solution but it works.

**Note**: This assumes that a year has 365 days (ignores leap non leap years) and months have 30 days.