# How to convert dateutil.relativedelta object to datetime.timedelta object?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-dateutil, relative-date

How can I convert a dateutil.relativedelta object to a datetime.timedelta object?

e.g.,

```
# pip install python-dateutil

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import timedelta

rel_delta = relativedelta(months=-2)
# How can I convert rel_delta to a timedelta object so that I can call total_seconds() ?
time_delta = ???(rel_delta)  
time_delta.total_seconds()  # call the timedelta.total_seconds() method
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, for one **huge** reason: *They don't store the same information.* `datetime.timedelta` only stores days, seconds, and milliseconds, whereas `dateutil.relativedelta` stores *every single time component* fed to it.

That `dateutil.relativedelta` does so is important for storing things such as a difference of 1 month, but since the length of a month can vary this means that there is no way at all to express the same thing in `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio_Vazquez-Abrams!  Now I get it -- the relativedata object stores data that is used when doing arithmetic with a datetime object, so it needs to have the same data types as datetime object.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is looking to convert a `relativedelta` to a `timedelta` *from a specific date,* simply add and subtract the known time:

```py
utcnow = datetime.utcnow()
rel_delta = relativedelta(months=-2)
time_delta = utcnow + rel_delta - utcnow  # e.g, datetime.timedelta(days=-62)
```

As [a commenter points out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912307/%C3%85smund), the resulting `timedelta` value will differ based on what month it is.

Comment: This is not well-defined. Replace `datetime.utcnow()` with `datetime(2000, 1, 1)`, `datetime(2000, 2, 1)` and `datetime(2000, 3, 1)` respectively and you'll get three different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you want to call `total_seconds`, it may be possible to refactor your code to avoid the conversion altogether. For example, consider a check on whether or not a user is over 18 years old:

```
datetime.date.today() - user['dateOfBirth'] < datetime.timedelta(days=365*18)
```

This check is not a good idea, because the timedelta object does not account for things like leap years. It's tempting to rewrite as:

```
datetime.date.today() - user['dateOfBirth'] < dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=18)
```

which would require comparing a timedelta (LHS) to a relativedelta (RHS), or converting one to the other. However, you can refactor the check to avoid this conversion altogether:

```
user['dateOfBirth'] + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=18) > datetime.date.today()
```