# asking user to input password after a specific period of time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, time

I am writing this function in python with the Tkinter module.

I want the user to enter the password when he/she presses `show`. But I only want to ask the user to enter a password if the last password was asked 15 minutes ago.

```
    def show(self):

    if self.showButton['text'] == "hide":
        self.showButton['text'] = "show"
        self.password_text_label.grid_forget()
        self.password_display_label.grid(row=6 + self.count, column=2, sticky=E, padx=5)
    else:
        popupWindow(root)   # this will ask for master-password if you want to see the password (Another Layer of security)
        self.showButton['text'] = "hide"
        self.password_display_label.grid_forget()
        self.password_text_label.grid(row=6 + self.count, column=2, sticky=E, padx=5)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you need. Are you trying to give the user 15 min to write the password or ...?

Comment: You can store the password for 15 mins, and then later set it to `None` and keep checking if the password has ever become `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable and store the last login time, then compare it to the current time. To get time difference you can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


minutes = 15

def askPasswd():
    global lastAsked
 
    if lastAsked is None or relativedelta(datetime.now(), lastAsked).minutes  >= minutes:
        lastAsked = datetime.now()

        top = Toplevel()
        Label(top, text='Password').pack()
        Entry(top).pack()
        
root = Tk()

lastAsked = None

askBtn = Button(root, text='Ask', command=askPasswd)
askBtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what about `datetime.timedelta`, inbuilt module.

Comment: @CoolCloud you can use that too. Using timedelta will take extra steps to do the same thing.Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12433233/12198502)