# Get the date a year from today in dd/mm/yyyy format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get a date an year from todays date into a variable.
Below is my code.

```
import time
import datetime
today = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
today_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, "%m/%d/%Y")
print (today_format)
exp_date = str(today_format + datetime.timedelta(days=365)).split(" ")
exp = exp_date[0]
print (exp)`
```

Above code prints:

```
2017-12-14 00:00:00
2018-12-14
```

Any idea how to get it to print 12/14/2018??

Comment: for subtracting any year, month or etc. take a look at here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871168/how-can-i-subtract-or-add-100-years-to-a-datetime-field-in-the-database-in-djang

Comment: `strptime` after a `strftime` doesn't make sense

Comment: I'd use years=1 rather than days=365, it'll handle leap years better.

Comment: @Octopus you can't using `datetime.timedelta`. It only accepts days, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours, weeks arguments

Comment: @ Loïc G. use dateutil.relativedelta

Comment: @Octopus Of course but mention it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `dateutil.relativedelta` package, you can do:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

one_year_from_now = datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(years=1)
date_formated = one_year_from_now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print date_formated
```

[how to install `dateutil` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879156/how-to-install-python-dateutil-on-windows)

Comment: "a year from today" typically means one year into the future, not the past.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the datetime module:

```
datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Prints:

```
'12/14/2017'
```

Comment: I need the output as a date a year from today in MM/DD/YYYY format and not MM-DD-YYYY format.
UI throws an error with MM-DD-YYYY format.

Comment: Use this code: `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` @Sel_Python

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('now') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party for this one, but had the same issue and this is my solution:

```
date1 = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
def monthreduct(date):
    
    def under10(date):
        if int(date[1]) < 10:
               date[1] = f'0{date[1]}'
               
    date = date.split('-')    
    date[1] = int(date[1])  
    if date[1] <= 1:
        date[0] = int(date[0]) - 1
        date[0] = str(date[0])
        date[1] = str(12)
    else:
        date[1] = int(date[1]) - 1
    date[1] = str(date[1])
    under10(date)
    return "-".join(date)
```

This will allow a date, for example 12-09-2030 to be adjusted to 12-08-2030.